# How to replace a group value to an empty string string using regex

Tags: regex

I have a string like

```
0||||0||||6567||||0
```

I want to replace 0 with empty string
So to match the 0 I have use below regex

```
(?:^(?<zero>0)\||\|(?<zero>0)\||\|(?<zero>0)$)
```

Now I want output as

```
emptystring||||emptystring ||||6567||||emptystring
```

Comment: [`\b0\b` replace by `''`](https://regex101.com/r/kZ9oP4/1)

Comment: not every 0 in numbers

Comment: @PriteshChhunchha did you try that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simply use word boundaries..

regex:

```
\b0\b
```

or

```
(?<![^|])0(?![^|])
```

replace with:

```
emptystring
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/sU2qC4/2)